# Extract only text from Rmd documents

Tags: r, markdown, knitr, r-markdown

Not even sure if this is possible, but is there a way to extract only the raw text portion of the .Rmd file and discard any code? 
Or basically converting an .Rmd file into .txt file within R?

I've tried the function `readLines`, but this makes a huuuuuge character with all kinds of (to me) useless meta-data.

Comment: any updates on the question? Did it work?

Comment: Still no avail :( Perhaps I can rephrase my problem this way: is there a reverse-knit? Instead of knitting a file to .Rmd, is there a way to import the text information from an .Rmd into R?

Comment: Please add example input you have and wanted output

Comment: Ok, while making a dummy file, to show my problem, it did seem to work! Very strange, seems like the file I had been working with was just corrupted. Readlines is the solution all along. Thanks for your persistent concern, I was just being very stupid?

Comment: Happens :-) You can accept my answer as it helped to solve your problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can `knit` document without evaluating and including code.

Here's an example of dummy document `foo.Rmd`:

> # Header 1
>
> foo
>
> ## Header 2
>
> bar
>
> ## Header 22
>
> foobar
>
> ```{r}
>   1
>   ```
>
> text text text
>
> ```{r}
>   print(2)
>   ```

We can knit this document using `knitr::knit("foo.Rmd")`, but in this case code chunks will be included in text. To deal with this we need to set `knitr` options:

```
library(knitr)
opts_chunk$set(list(echo = FALSE, eval = FALSE))
knit("foo.Rmd")
```

This command will create output document `foo.md` only with text.

Comment: Hi there! So if I now have this `"foo.Rmd"` saved on my PC, how can I read it in that I only have the text elements in my workspace?

Comment: @Inkling you need to run those three code lines and then: `readLines("foo.md")`. Let me know how it goes

Comment: I tried `readLines` on one of my own .Rmd files but then I get a bunch of HTML info. I downloaded the .Rmd from a github repositry. if I normally open the .Rmd by double clicking on it, it opens up in a new tab in Rstudio and I can read the text. But I want to do operations on this text, therefore read in the content of the .Rmd into my workspace. Does this make sense at all?

Comment: @Inkling Sorry, but I can't understand your question. Can you update your original question with: 1. Input you have; 2. Wanted output